# Which MySQL JOIN do I use?

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
SELECT comments.comment, comments.title, userBase.uID, userBase.fname FROM comments JOIN userBase WHERE comment.ID=users.ID AND comments.uID='$uID' AND comments.title='$title'
```

However this only gives me the information from the comments database when using:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    print_r($row);
```

Comment: After fixing my typo's this did it:

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT comments.comment, comments.title, userBase.uID, userBase.fname 
FROM comments 
 INNER JOIN userBase ON comments.uID=userBase.uID 
 AND comments.uID='$uID' 
 AND comments.title='$title'")or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, this is the query

```
SELECT comments.comment, comments.title, userBase.uID, userBase.fname 
FROM comments 
INNER JOIN userBase ON comment.ID=users.ID 
                    AND comments.uID='$uID' 
                    AND comments.title='$title'
```

Anyway there are several problems with your questions:

- I assume `comments` and `userBase` are tables, **not** database
- You have an `AND` just after the `WHERE` clause, which makes no sense at all
- It is not clear what the relation is. Are you sure that you want to equate `comments.ID` with `userBase.ID`? In this case you are using the `ID` key for the foreign key in the comments, which is not very readable. You may want to use something like `comments.user_id`

**Edit:** Just to be clear, there is an alternative syntax for joins, which uses the `WHERE` keyword. You could rewrite the above as

```
SELECT comments.comment, comments.title, userBase.uID, userBase.fname 
FROM comments, userBase 
WHERE comment.ID=users.ID 
  AND comments.uID='$uID' 
  AND comments.title='$title'
```

but it is not the SQL standard. It works in MySQL, and I think also in SQLServer, but I'm not completely sure about the other db vendors. In any case, the problem with your query is that you were mixing the two different syntaxes.

Comment: The AND is a cut and paste typo, as for the id, yeah i truncated my actual variable just for this. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Andrea what is the reasoning behind not using "WHERE" in a JOIN?

Comment: There is an alternative syntax for joins, using WHERE. But you are mixing the two.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a Try:

```
SELECT c.comment, c.title, u.uID, u.fname
FROM comments c, userBase u
WHERE c.ID = u.ID
and c.title = '$title'
and c.uID = '$uID'
```

I'm assuming all your variables have been initialized and have some value.  For Primary Key's you don't need a ' (quotation) around the value.  Also, you need to pick whether you're using a JOIN style statement or a WHERE = style statement.

Here is more info on JOINS and WHERE = statements.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: Blah! I'd never recommend the comma-delimited syntax. Always better to recommend the ISO Join syntax.

Comment: @Thomas why would you not recommend comma-delimited syntax?

Comment: @Fred - A host of reasons. First, it was outmoded the moment the ISO/ANSI syntax came out. That was 1989. Second, there are certain types of joins that simply cannot be done using that syntax. Third, your intent is clearer using ISO syntax (i.e. it is easier to read). Did you intend to create a cross join? Can't tell by looking at the From clause. The reader needs to dig into the Where clause to find out. In addition, the join conditions are all muddied with the filtering conditions. There really aren't any good reasons for using the comma-delimited syntax at this stage.

Comment: @Thomas ahh I see, I was intending to do an inner join, but i'm still learning. This helped if anyone else stumbles on this.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595526/pros-cons-of-mysql-joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595526/pros-cons-of-mysql-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Inner join will give you all rows from both tables that satisfy the join condition, this join condition is specified in the on clause, (which you have omitted).  In contrast a left join will give you all rows from the left table in the join (the first table), and any rows from the right table that satisfy the join condition, and the opposite is true for a right join.

I think what you are looking for in your SQL is :

```
SELECT comments.comment, comments.title, userBase.uID, userBase.fname 
FROM comments INNER JOIN userBase ON comment.ID=users.ID 
WHERE comments.uID='$uID' AND comments.title='$title'
```